# I have 2 classes in Bluej and want to make a field in one of the classes be of type of the other class. How would I do this?

Tags: java, class, bluej

I have made 2 classes in my project in bluej and I have to link them by making a new field in the main class of type of the second class.

What is the syntax to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I may be interpreting the question wrong but, assuming your classes are Class1 and Class2, you can have Class1 take in an instance of Class2 so:

```
public class Class1{

      Class2 otherClass;

      public Class1(Class2 otherClass){
          this.otherClass = otherClass;
      }
 }
```

Now Class1 has an instance of Class2 it can play with.

You may also just have Class1 always create a Class2 object instead of passing one into it so:

```
public class Class1{

      Class2 otherClass;

      public Class1(){
           otherClass = new Class2();
      }
 }
```